# Php - how to check whether a row exists and display different things based on the result?

Tags: php

I have an attraction page that displays some information from the database, and I've put a favorite button with each display. This is my code:

```
$villageId = $_GET['village']; 
$sql    = "SELECT `AttractionID`, `Name`, `Location`, `Description`, `Airport`, `imglink`,`imglink2`,`imglink3`,`imglink4`,`imglink5`  FROM `attractions` WHERE `AttractionID`='$villageId'";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

if (!$result) {
    echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}



while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<div class='attractions6'>";
    echo "<div class='attractions5'>";
    echo $row['Name']; 

    echo "<span title='Add to Favorites'>" . "<a href='favourite.php?village=" . $row['AttractionID'] . "'>" . 

 "<img src='img/fav.png'></a>";

    echo  "</span>" ;
    echo "<br />" ;
    echo "<br />";
    echo "</div>";

    echo $row['Description'];
    echo "<br />" ;

    echo "<br />";
    echo " Location: ";

    echo $row['Location'] ." ";
    echo "<br />" ;
    echo "<br />";

    echo " Nearest Airport: ".$row['Airport'] ." ";
    echo "<br />" ;

    echo "<br />";
    echo "</div>";
    echo '<a href="'.$row['imglink'].'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$row['imglink'].' " height="200" width="550"></a>';
    echo "<br />";
    echo '<a href="'.$row['imglink2'].'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$row['imglink2'].' " height="180" width="180"></a>';
    echo "&nbsp";
    echo '<a href="'.$row['imglink3'].'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$row['imglink3'].' " height="180" width="180"></a>';
    echo "&nbsp";
    echo '<a href="'.$row['imglink4'].'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$row['imglink4'].' " height="180" width="180"></a>';
    echo "&nbsp";
    echo '<a href="'.$row['imglink5'].'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$row['imglink5'].' " height="180" width="180"></a>';



    echo "&nbsp;";
    //This is the favorite button. If the user clicks on it the script 
    //will redirect to the favourite.php page where the database will be 
    //checked for duplicates in the attractionID field and will save the favorite. 

    echo "<br />";
    echo "<br />";

}

mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

I have the following code which I'm using on other places of the website that can check whether the input already exists:

```
$sql="SELECT `ID`,`AttractionID`  FROM `favourites` 
      WHERE `ID`='$ID' AND `AttractionID`='$villageId'  ";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    header('location:attraction.php?village='.$villageId);
}
```

On the attraction page how can I make it so that if the user already saved this entry to favorites - I will display picture1 and if they didn't - I will display picture two?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any `user_id` that helps you know what user favorited what attraction

Comment: $sql="SELECT `ID`,`AttractionID`  FROM `favourites` 
      WHERE `ID`='$ID' AND `AttractionID`='$villageId'  ";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    header('location:attraction.php?village='.$villageId);
}

Comment: an the session ID which I will compare

Comment: Sidenote: You're mixing MySQL APIs, they do NOT mix. You're using `mysql_*` in one body of code and `mysqli_*` in the other. Stay with "one", being the latter. ;-)

Comment: in your database where is `user_id`? Like how can you `select` what the user favorited?

Comment: again this is the code I will use to select what the user has favourites: $sql="SELECT `ID`,`AttractionID`  FROM `favourites` 
      WHERE `ID`='$ID' AND `AttractionID`='$villageId'  ";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    header('location:attraction.php?village='.$villageId);
}

Comment: I am lost, sorry. you're selecting `WHERE attraction_id='$villageId'` so each village has 1 attraction? Or how does all this work? just as a clue as I don't understand your database. What you can do is put all the `id`'s the user favorited into an array then use [in_array](http://www.php.net/in_array) function to check each row.

Comment: no village is the ID i'm using to pass the attraction ID in the URL. When the user insterts a favoutite in the database I'm saving his session ID and the attraction ID that has been chosen. I don't want to select all saved ID's i just wnat to check weather the current one i'm displaying is already saved in favourites. I have done everything till that point, and just need to figure out how to display picture one if the attraction is saved in the usre favourites, and how to display picture 2 if not.